# Globally setting CPU affinity

Tags: cpu, numa

Is there a way to make all processes, except the ones I intentionally set otherwise with `taskset` or `numactl` use only certain cores/memory (without looping through every thread of every process and setting it myself)?

A few more details: I have 2 physical CPU chips, each with 4 cores / 8 threads along with a total of 256 GB RAM. The memory is not evenly distributed between the two CPU memory buses. I would like the one with significantly less memory to be the general-purpose one with most programs (e.g. background tasks) running on that CPU and with its memory. Then on the CPU with most of the memory run special tasks that I will be timing the speed of and want them to not have an CPU-contention, NUMA, or anything like that.

Comment: You may enclose your programs to virtual machines using KVM/libvirt, you may specify vCPU/cores mapping in the XML deffinition file.

Comment: systemd?  Or something else?  Have you researched cgroups?

Comment: @JaroslavKucera this wouldn't limit the base system's processes to the given CPU, and the other set of processes is a small set.

Comment: @outurnate I guess all of the processes would be started by systemd, but just setting its affinity/numa/cgroup wouldn't necessarily effect all of its children, even just setting the affinity of a process doesn't effect its threads. Unless there is a way to 'hook' systemd initialization to change it before it forks any processes. Also, wouldn't cgroups have the same issue in that every process would need to be added?

Comment: child processes automatically belong to the parent cgroup.  systemd also creates a hierarchy of cgroups for slices/scopes/service.  Unfortunately, you can't set a cpuset for a slice.  I've got answer - will type up

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be achieved by modifying systemd config.  First, change the default affinity settings in `/etc/systemd/system.conf` by adding:

```
[Manager]
CPUAffinity=1
```

Then, under you unit, clear the affinity, then reset it to your desired CPUs

```
[Exec]
CPUAffinity=
CPUAffinity=2-4
```

Comment: Sorry for delay, but this does seem to work! Thanks!

Comment: @thaimin glad to hear it!